# Selenium Python Slow character speed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

is there a way to make my send key goes slower when it types the character.
Having a hard time to slowdown how fast it types.
I tried using Sleep method, but that doesn't work.

```
A('Starting up browser...')
e=l()
e.add_argument('disable-infobars')
B=k.Chrome(options=e)
B.implicitly_wait(5)
n=[0.02,0.04,0.03]
o=[F,J]
def f(word):
        A=word;A=list(A);C=[]
        for E in i(10):C.append([G(U),d.BACKSPACE])
        F=G(o)
        if F:
                I=G([1,2,3])
                for E in i(I):A.insert(G(i(j(A))),G(C))
                A=[C for B in A for C in B]
        D=B.find_element_by_css_selector('.selfTurn input')
        for J in A:K=G(n);D.send_keys(J);H(K)
        H(0.2);D.send_keys(d.ENTER)
A('Navigating to the JKLM website...')
B.get(m)
g=J
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your code with the lack of proper formatting and the use of single letter variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can send keys to the element with `action_chains` `send_keys` method instead of using the selenium `driver` `send_keys` method.
I would show that on your code, but it appears to be too abnormal, so I will give you the general example.
You need to add import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

then to initialize the `actions` object with

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```

then to send text with actions to method located by `.selfTurn input` css_selector

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.selfTurn input')
action.click(element)
action.send_keys("your_text")
action.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to send keys like people typing because there is any detection if type speed is fast than normal, is right?

At selenium you can use `send_keys`, but there's no time interval arguments associated with type. See [Selenium Document](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.html#ActionChains.send_keys)

So use custom `send_keys` with some edit like below.

```
def send_keys(self, *keys_to_send, time_interval):
    """
    Sends keys to current focused element.

    :Args:
     - keys_to_send: The keys to send.  Modifier keys constants can be found in the
       'Keys' class.
    """
    typing = keys_to_typing(keys_to_send)

    for key in typing:
        self.key_down(key)
        self.key_up(key)
        time.sleep(time_interval)  # what I insert to delay input time

    return self
```